# What is the C++ equivalent of PHP's hash_hmac function?

Tags: php, c++, porting, sha256

I'm porting a PHP application to C++. The PHP application is using this function:

> hash_hmac — Generate a keyed hash value using the HMAC method

If I have this code, what is it actually doing?

```
$sStr = hash_hmac ('sha256', $mydata,$mykey, $raw = true)
```

I know it encrypts some data using sha256 and my key, but how can I perform this in C++?

I've found the [hmac](http://www.ouah.org/ogay/hmac/) and [sha2](http://www.ouah.org/ogay/sha2/) libraries, but am not sure if they are what I need.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would consider looking into [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/), a portable and complete cryptographic library (despite its name, it doesn't just do SSL).  It has an [HMAC library](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/hmac.html) which you can surely wrap to get similar function.

Here's an example on how to use OpenSSL' HMAC library, taken from [another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242665/understanding-engine-initialization-in-openssl) (annotations mine):

```
  // Initialize HMAC object.
HMAC_CTX ctx;
HMAC_CTX_init(&ctx);

  // Set HMAC key.
HMAC_Init_ex(&ctx, key, 16, EVP_sha256(), NULL);

  // May be called repeatedly to insert all your data.
HMAC_Update(&ctx, data, 8);

  // Finish HMAC computation and fetch result.
HMAC_Final(&ctx, result, &result_len);

  // Done with HMAC object.
HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
```