# Access Azure blob storage using C++

Tags: c++, qt, rest, azure, azure-storage

Was looking around and found a few answers that suggests that I should use REST. But how would I integrate this in Qt/c++? Could anyone link some examples of this or maybe a few lines of code? Would really appreciate it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471810/accessing-azure-storage-tables-from-c-code/9476451#9476451

Answer (score 3):

It took me a lot of time to achieve it. The trickiest thing is that you have to decode your primary key. With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242665/understanding-engine-initialization-in-openssl), I've decided to use OpenSSL and I've made the following code.

```
QString datastring = "GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:" + date + "\nx-ms-version:2009-09-19\n/myStorage/\ncomp:list";
QByteArray ba = datastring.toUtf8();

unsigned char* signature = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(ba.data());
QByteArray kba = QByteArray::fromBase64("theStorageAccountKey");
unsigned char* key = (unsigned char*) kba.data();
unsigned char result[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
unsigned int result_len;
ENGINE_load_builtin_engines();
ENGINE_register_all_complete();

HMAC_CTX ctx;
HMAC_CTX_init(&ctx);
HMAC_Init_ex(&ctx, key, strlen((const char*)key), EVP_sha256(), NULL);
HMAC_Update(&ctx, signature, strlen((const char*)signature));
HMAC_Final(&ctx, result, &result_len);
HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);

QByteArray array = QByteArray::fromRawData((char*)result, result_len);
array = array.toBase64();
qDebug() << "signature hash" << array;

QString version = "2009-09-19";

//requesting the list of container to Windows Azure
QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl("http://myStorage.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list"));
request.setRawHeader("Authorization","SharedKey myStorage:" + array);
request.setRawHeader("x-ms-date", date.toStdString().c_str());
request.setRawHeader("x-ms-version", version.toStdString().c_str());
QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(manageCloudReply()));
```

I hope it'll help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471810/accessing-azure-storage-tables-from-c-code). It covers what you ask and outlines couple of freely available C++ libraries, which you could incorporate to access Azure services.