# Beginner's C++ memory allocation mess

Tags: c++, memory-management, openssl, hmac

I am trying the code bellow. The thing is: some times work and some times doesn't! I am using the OpenSSL library, but I believe my mistake is something simple, C related.

```
int test_c(string to_sign, string key)
{
    const void* key_void = (const void*)key.c_str();
    int key_size = key.size();

    const unsigned char* data_char = (const unsigned char*)to_sign.c_str();
    int data_size = to_sign.size();

    unsigned int res_f_len = data_size*8;
    unsigned char* res_f = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*res_f_len);

    HMAC_CTX ctx;
    HMAC_CTX_init(&ctx);
    HMAC_Init_ex(&ctx, key_void, key_size, EVP_sha256(), NULL);
    HMAC_Update(&ctx, data_char, data_size);
    HMAC_Final(&ctx, res_f, &res_f_len);
    HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);

    return strlen(res_f);
}
```

**When I say it doesn't work, I mean, for the same data and key, different results are returned!**

Comment: If this is C, then you don't need casts around `void *`s (including the return value of `malloc()`). If this is C++, please don't tag with `c`.

Comment: Your use of strlen(res_f) indicates that the result string size is unknown.  Do the HMAC functions fill/zero res_f?  If not, malloc returns you a pointer to memory filled with undefined values (as in, garbage) and strlen works by looking for 0s.

Comment: Clever guess. The result size is unknown, I know the size of the key on the other hand (60 bytes). HMAC_Final fills the res_f with data.

Comment: @Blazer: Yes, but does it fill it completely, or just enough to contain encoded data? You hand in the address to res_f_len to HMAC_Final.  I went to github, searched "HMAC_Final", included C++ results only, and saw code similar to `uint32_t len = 0; HMAC_Final(&m_ctx, m_digest, &len); return std::vector<uint8_t>(m_digest, m_digest + len);`.  This hints to me that HMAC_Final mutates the length parameter and that you might want to use that.

Comment: Why isn't the result length in `res_f_len`?  It seems like a hashed result could have 0s in it, which would cause `strlen()` to return too small a number.  It _also_ seems like the result could be entirely non-zero, in which case `strlen()` would stop on the first zero it finds in random garbage after the result.  Only in the case where there's exactly 0 zero in the buffer, and it's the first byte after the result would `strlen()` return the answer you want, and that seems like a dicey proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than return `strlen(res_f);` as the length of the output buffer, you need to return `res_f_len`.

There are three things that could happen with `strlen()` in your code:

- If the HMAC message digest has a byte that equals zero, `strlen` will return a length that's shorter than the HMAC message digest.
- If the HMAC message digest has no zero bytes, then `strlen` will read beyond the message digest, leading to one of two outcomes:

  - `strlen` reads through garbage in memory after the message digest, eventually stopping on a random 0.  `strlen` returns a value that's way too large.
  - If you're exceedingly lucky, the first byte after the message digest is 0, in which case `strlen` returns the actual length of the message digest.

So, only in the last scenario will you get the right value.  That pretty much seems wrong.

It appears tht `HMAC_Final` does update the length argument you pass to it.  ([See the example in the top-voted answer to this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242665/understanding-engine-initialization-in-openssl).)  That's why you pass a pointer-to-int.  You should just return this updated value.

Comment: Owh, after wasting about 10 hours on this and messed up my whole program it was really exactly what you write here!!! Thanks a ton!